# SeleniumRC/Perl dynamic XPath selector not working

Tags: perl, xpath, selenium, selenium-rc

This is more a question for XPath syntax than anything else.

I have multiple product pages on a site that have multiple products on each product pages.  Each product has a unique ID for the add-to-cart button.  I'm trying to return all of the unique ID's so that I can add a couple of the products to the bag.  Searching with XPath seems to be the correct solution for this.  I have the following code for querying the HTML with XPath and returning the unique ID's:

```
$XPATH_COUNT = $sel->get_xpath_count("//div[\@class='quick-info-link']/a");

@my_array;
$my_array[0] = $sel->get_attribute("//div[\@class='quick-info-link']/a/\@id");
print $my_array[0];
$count = 0;

while( $count < $XPATH_COUNT )
{
    $arrayCount=0;
    $a = "//";

    foreach( @my_array )
    {
        $tmp = "a[\@id!='" . $my_array[$arrayCount] . "' and ";
        $b .= $tmp;
        $d .= "]";
        $arrayCount++;
    }

    $c = "img[\@alt='Quick Shop']";
    $e = $c . $d . "/\@id";
    $xpath_query = $a . $b . $e;
    $my_array[$count] = $sel->get_attribute($xpath_query);
    $count++;
}
```

The output of the first run of this is an XPath query that looks like this:

```
//a[@id!='quickview-link-PROD7029' and img[@alt='Quick Shop']]/@id
```

Which correctly returns quickview-link-PROD6945.  The second run produces this:

```
//a[@id!='quickview-link-PROD7029' and a[@id!='quickview-link-PROD6945' and img[@alt='Quick Shop']]]/@id
```

Which throws an error in my SeleniumRC terminal window of ERROR: Element [..xpath query..] not found on session.

I am aware of the possible use of indexes (i.e. adding an `[i]` to the end of the XPath query) to access elements on the page, however this isn't something that has worked for me in Selenium.

Any help would be great.  Thanks for your time,
Steve

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Are those `@id` really uniques, or do you want to get the uniques? It looks like you are trying to "iterate" over this uniques ids by sequentially adding a filter to the XPath expression. I don't think this is the right way...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //a[@id!='quickview-link-PROD7029' 
>     and a[@id!='quickview-link-PROD6945' and
> ```
>
> img[@alt='Quick Shop']
>                ]
>          ]/@id
>
> Which throws an error in my SeleniumRC
>   terminal window of ERROR: Element
>   [..xpath query..] not found on session

It would greatly help if you provide the XML document on which the XPath expression is applied and explain which node(s) you want to select.

Without this necessary information:

**The most obvious reason for this problem** is that the above expression is looking for `a` elements that have an `a` child with some property.

Usually an `a` element doesn't have any `a` children.

**What you really want is something like**:

```
//a[@id != 'quickview-link-PROD7029' 
  and 
   @id != 'quickview-link-PROD6945' and img[@alt='Quick Shop']
   ]/@id
```

This can be simplified a bit:

```
//a[img[@alt='Quick Shop']/@id
                           [not(. = 'quickview-link-PROD7029' 
                               or 
                                . =  'quickview-link-PROD6945'
                                )
                            ]
```